# Виджет поиска во Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-search-view, backbutton

Что есть: 
**Activity**, всю часть пространства которого занимает два **Fragment** (попеременно). Первый **Fragment** содержит виджет поиска **SearchView** и список на основе **RecyclerView**. По нажатию на элемент списка происходит смена первого **Fragment** на второй. Второй **Fragment** будет содержать только список (другой) на основе **RecyclerView**.

Что нужно делать:
По нажатию на Back Button (назад) нужно, чтобы в **Activity** сначала происходил откат по стеку в **FragmentManager** путем вызова `popBackStack()`, затем когда останется только начальный (первый) **Fragment**, необходимо закрыть **Activity**

Проблема:
Очевидно, из-за фокуса на **SearchView** не работает Back Button, соответственно в **Activity** не вызывается `OnBackPressed()` со всей начинкой по откату стека.
Долгие часы гугла дали мысль, что кошерным местом для использования **SearchView** является только **Toolbar**, но это не является допустимым решением по нескольким причинам:

1. Хочу иметь виджет именно во **Fragment**'е;
2. Из всего не работает только логика по клавише "назад";
3. В планах перенести оба **Fragment**'a в BottomSheet в совсем другую **Activity**, в которой виджет поиска в **Toolbar** будет не к месту.

Нужна помощь по решению проблемы, или иной виджет поиска, если вдруг я его упустил.

Comment: То есть фактически у вас не работает кнопка "назад", а вопрос называется "Поиск в Fragment", хотя проблем с реализацией, собственно, поиска нет ..

Comment: @pavlofff Проблема с виджетом поиска, я не указывал в названии вопроса на проблемы с процессом поиска